# How to get server username in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

What I need to do is to retrieve SQL server username for current user using my app. In SQL I can simply do it using `Select SYSTEM_USER`. I want to do it in my shiny app through libraries `pool` and `DBI` but can't find apriopriate command which can retrieve server user name. When I try with this:

```
DBI::dbGetInfo()
```

then the following error shows up:
*Error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetInfo’ for signature ‘"missing"’*

Do you have any ideas how to get current SQL username?

Comment: How do you define the connection? if `conn` is your connection, then `DBI::dbGetInfo(conn)$username` will work., but as `username` is usually needed to establish the connection I'm not sure `dbGetInfo` is really useful here

Comment: Can't you use `DBI::dbGetQuery(conn,"Select SYSTEM_USER")`, where `conn` is your connection from dbConnect?

Comment: I use `pool` library to set connection - `pool <- pool::dbPool(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "SQL_DSN")`

Comment: @Baroque I thought about it as well now:) I think it solves the problem